# Can i launch my application without certificate on real device(iPod)?

Tags: iphone, xcode, digital-certificate

does Apple offer developers to test their application on real devices without publishing if they haven't certificates?

It is necessary for me in education purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry to this but you **CANNOT** install an application on your device without Apple's Certificate.There is only one exception where the certicate can be availed for free and that is for higher educational institutions.

For more details follow [this](http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/university/) link